# JavaScript, How to show 'current' data in a tooltip without polling?

Tags: javascript, tooltip, title

I have an html element, (lets say for simplicity) a label, and it has a title, so that a tooltip appears when you hover over the label.

I would like the tooltip to show a snapshot of some associated 'current' data.  In actuality, the current price of the object that the label points to, but an analogue of this could be any data that potentially changes with time.

In native JavaScript, how can I detect the activation of the tooltip, so that I can re-calc the data before the tooltip is shown?

I know that I could use setInterval() or something to keep the title string current, but it would be more efficient to only re-calculate the title string when the tooltip is shown.

Comment: Looking at the javascript event list, I can't find [anything that matches](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp). I think you will have to use a combination of `mouseenter`, `setInterval()` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: Can include `html`, `js`, `css` at Question ? , create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work, but you'll be at the mercy of the latency of the request for updating the data (assuming that the source of the updated price data is a http request or socket connection) and that probably won't be quicker than the browser will display the tooltip. It's certainly not going to be consistent or reliable.

```
<p id="text" title="initialtitle">Text</p>
<script>
    var n = 0;

    document.getElementById("text");
        text.onmouseover = function() {
            n++;
            text.title = n;
    };
</script>
```

Depending on the specifics of what you're doing and how much room for maneuver you have, another solution could be to open a WebSocket to a server which then updates all clients with the updated price information when it changes. That way the data is sent to the cleint as fast as possible without constant http polling, and timers aren't necessary.

Of course, if the source of the data is a calculation within the JavaScript itself without having to get information from a server, then a mere modification of the above for your needs could suit.

[Here's a jsfiddle to play around with.](https://jsfiddle.net/mg8jantz/)

Comment: This looks good on first view.  Data for the tooltip will be locally cached so no problem with latency.  I was thinking I would have to trap for the tooltip appearing, but working with onmouseover is nice lateral thinking.

Comment: Update: Have successfully used onMouseOver event to update tooltip.  Instead of a fixed timestamp ("Expires at 13:59:59") user now sees 'time remaining' ("Expires in 2 hours, 12 minutes and 12 seconds").  Much obliged for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `data-*` attribute of element to store values, setting `element.title` to `data-*` of element , `onmouseover` , `onmouseleave` events

```js
var elem = document.querySelector("div");

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  elem.dataset.tooltip = 1+ +elem.dataset.tooltip;
}, 1000);

elem.onmouseover = elem.onmouseleave = function(e) {
  console.log(e)
  this.title = this.dataset.tooltip;
}
```

```html
<div data-tooltip="0" title="0">hover</div>
```

Comment: This is interesting, but goes a bit further than I currently need.  The onmouseover trick is the key here, similar to Adrian's answer.  Will uptick this answer, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code help you

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" id="test" onChange="setTitle(this)" title="testing...">Test1</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#test').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  $('#test').attr('title',$('#test').html());
});
// Run below code in your console to change your div value
//$(".test").html("test2");

</script>
```

First run above code in you browser. and check tooltip will be 'testing...'.
Then run

```
$(".test").html("test2");
```

In your browser console to change your div html and then check your tooltip again. you will see the exact text of div.

Comment: See OP at _"In native JavaScript"_

Comment: Yep, native JS, sorry.  But thanks for the answer, and it will possibly be useful to others using JQuery.